# How to make Some text bold in a paragraph while generating from novacode docx library in c#

Tags: c#, docx, novacode-docx

I want to make some text bold like that..
•   **Basic** – There are no Cybersecurity

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this is to insert the bolded text separately into the same paragraph.

```
// Create the proper formats first
Formatting bold = new Formatting();
bold.Bold = true;

Formatting notBold = new Formatting();

// Create the file
DocX doc = DocX.Create("test.docx");

// Insert the text you want with the proper formatting for each section
Paragraph para = doc.InsertParagraph();
para.InsertText("not bold text ", false, notBold);
para.InsertText("bold text ", false, bold);
para.InsertText("not bold text", false, notBold);

doc.Save();
```

This will output:

> not bold text **bold text** not bold text